# OpenCV Trackers Confusion: Legacy vs Non Legacy

Tags: opencv

Confused between **OpenCV trackers** and **Legacy trackers**. Why are some trackers listed both in Legacy and Non Legacy?

[image]

[image]

I was working with OpenCV tackers, e.g., trackerCSRT which is in legacy now. Why it went to legacy and which tracker replaced it?

Can't find more details on OpenCV Legacy Support. The way I understand it is that older algorithms are taken to Legacy. When does an algorithm goes to legacy? Are these algorithms deprecated after a certain period?